# Python: Remove exponential in Strings

Tags: pandas

I have been trying to remove the exponential in a string for the longest time to no avail.

The column involves strings with alphabets in it and also long numbers of more than 24 digits. I tried converting the column to string with .astype(str) but it just reads the line as "1.234123E+23". An example of the table is

```
A

345223423dd234324

1.234123E+23
```

how do i get the table to show the full string of digits in pandas?

Comment: Try doing this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689125/how-to-get-rid-of-pandas-converting-large-numbers-in-excel-sheet-to-exponential

Comment: ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'
The column is a string due to the first input having letters in it :(

Answer (score 0):

```
b = "1.234123E+23"
str(int(float(b)))
```

output is '123412299999999992791040'
no idea how to do it in pandas with mixed data type in column