# How to write big integer from json to csv using pandas to_csv

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I use an API that returns a json string that I write to a csv file using pandas - `to_csv`. Some of the fields are strings and some are numeric.
One of the fields is a long serial number written to csv in a scientific way and therefore its recent digits appear as zeros, for example:
json - `7052770924403150081`,
csv - `7.05277E+18`,
reading this csv in another python program - `7052770924403150000`

How can I keep this number in the csv file as without any change? Of course without damaging the other fields in the file?

I tried `float_format` but it did not help: `df.to_csv (self.csv_video, float_format = '%f')`

Would appreciate help.

Comment: Ensure the column is parsed as an integer or a string, not as a floating-point number.

Comment: why are you using pandas to create your csv?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get rid of pandas converting large numbers in excel sheet to exponential?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689125/how-to-get-rid-of-pandas-converting-large-numbers-in-excel-sheet-to-exponential)

Comment: Did you try adding `pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%f' % x)` before your export?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's also a good question, of course. `csv` would likely do fine here...

Comment: @AKX not only would it do fine, it would straight-forwardly preserve the exact digits in the large integer, since it isn't being converted to a `numpy` numeric type, in this case, a `np.float64` I presume, in which case, it loses that information.

Comment: This is a code that a former co-worker wrote and I just need to update it. Prefers not to make massive changes but only spot as much as possible.

Comment: @oferbin You would need to show the relevant code, then.